# Unable to add AudioKit.framework to an older project

Tags: audiokit

I have been able to add a downloaded version of AudioKit IOS to a new project by simply selecting AudioKit.framework in Linked Frameworks and Libraries in my Xcode project. For some reason I am unable to do the same for an older existing project. It shows up in the Frameworks folder but unable to import AudioKit. I tried adding the path to Framework Search Paths but still no luck. Any suggestions? I have tried the suggestions offered from similar questions as well.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a whole lot to go on, but trying cleaning your build folder.  Also, try copying the framework into the project instead of pointing to it in another folder.  Just see if that works, and if so, investigate what might be wrong with the reference.  Happy to help out more and even do a screen share since these problems are hard to describe completely on a SO question.

Comment: Copying the AudioKit Framework to the folder of the project works. It must have something to do with the search path. Thanks.